# How to print the button that calls a function in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, lambda

I've been writing a piece of Tkinter code that generates an array of buttons. Each button calls the same function. The function (button_press) is supposed to print the button that clicked it. What code should I put in to make button_press print the button that pressed it?

I've heard that Lambda is helpful, but I'm unsure about what to do.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_buttons()
        self.create_mines()

    def create_buttons(self):
        self.buttons = []
        for y in range(16):
            self.buttons.append([])
            for x in range(30):
                self.buttons[y].append(x)
                self.buttons[y][x] = tk.Button(command = self.button_press)
                self.buttons[y][x].grid(column = str(x), row = str(y))

    def create_mines(self):
        self.mine_list = []
        for mines in range(99):
            self.yValue = random.randint(0, 15)
            self.xValue = random.randint(0, 29)
            if self.buttons[self.yValue][self.xValue] in self.mine_list:
                mines += 1
            else:
                self.mine_list.append(self.buttons[self.yValue][self.xValue])

    def button_press(self):
        #?????

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(master = root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) does a great job documenting all of tkinter

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Okay, I've finished reading it, would widget be the correct event attribute to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers get one argument, an event, that has multiple attributes, including the widget that caught the event.  Command functions, unfortunately, do not get an argument, not even the widget that caught the click invoking the command.

So if you want the command function for different buttons to do different things, you must pass a different function.  In you case, you need 30 x 16 = 480 different functions.  Replace

```
            self.buttons[y][x] = tk.Button(command = self.button_press)
```

with, for instance,

```
            self.buttons[y][x] = tk.Button(
                command=lambda x=x, y=y: print(f'{x},{y}'))
```

This is one of multiple ways to create a different function for each button.  This is a conventional answer to this question.

An alternative is to not use the button command option, but to bind button clicks to a handler that gets an event that includes the button clicked.  Then add the information about each button needed for the click handler to each button, rather than to a command function.  Here is a complete development version of the game, for testing.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, rows, columns):
        self.master = master
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_buttons()
        self.create_mines()

    def create_buttons(self):
        self.buttons = []
        for y in range(self.rows):
            self.buttons.append([])
            for x in range(self.columns):
                button = tk.Button()
                button.y = y
                button.x = x
                button.mine = False
                button.grid(column=x, row=y)
                button.bind('<Button-1>', self.button_press)
                self.buttons[y].append(button)

    def create_mines(self):
        self.mines = set()
        mine_num = 0
        while mine_num < self.rows * self.columns // 5:
            x = random.randint(0, self.columns-1)
            y = random.randint(0, self.rows-1)
            button = self.buttons[y][x]
            if button not in self.mines:
                button.mine = True
                button['background'] = 'red'
                self.mines.add(button)
                mine_num += 1

    def button_press(self, event):
        b = event.widget
        label = 'Mine' if b.mine else 'Free'
        print(f'{label} {b.x}-{b.y}')


root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root, rows=16, columns=30)
app.mainloop()
```

For a game, expose mines when clicked, not when created ;0).

Answer (score 1):

For the function `button_press` to be able to print the button that clicked it, you need to pass in that button as a variable.

So maybe the function definition for `button_press` should be something like

```
def button_press(self, x, y):
    print("Button (%d,%d)" % (x,y))
```

And when you create the button, you could do something like

`self.buttons[y][x] = tx.Button(command = (lambda : self.button_press(x,y)))`

This means that when the button is clicked, it calls the lambda function, which calls button_press with the x and y of the button. Lambdas are pretty cool, and are definitely worth reading more about.

Comment: That seems to be a step in the correct direction, but it always prints the following: Button (29,15)

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be button bindings (thanks @pstatix)!

Add

```
self.buttons[y][x].bind('<Button-1>', self.button_press)
```

after

```
self.buttons[y][x].grid(column = str(x), row = str(y))
```

Change

```
def button_press(self):
```

to

```
def button_press(self, event):
    print(event.widget)
```

and move it above

```
def create_buttons(self)
```